# How to write such a SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables here. The first is `user` table, and the other is `order` table.
I want to select those users who has successful `order` record(s).
A success  `order` record means that the field `origin_cost` not equals to `0` and the field `status` should be `S`.
[image]

[image]

Below is my SQL statement:

```sql
select *
  from api_user user
 inner join pay_app_orders order
    on user.SNO = order.user_id
 where order.origin_cost != 0 and order.status = 'S'
```

But there are some same `user` records, i want to get the distinct `user` record, how to resolve this?
[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
select
 a.*,
 b.*
from
 user a
 left join order b on (b.key = a.key)
where
 b.status = 's'
 and b.origin_cost > 0
```

Comment: But there are some same user records.  How to resolve this?

Comment: The b conditions in the WHERE clause makes the LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: a and b are poor table aliases, chose something that makes sense, e.g. u for user and o for order.

Comment: "_don't agree_"?!? The FROM/ON builds a result - for all joins. When it's LEFT JOIN, you'll have null values for non-matching right side table rows. If you use WHERE to filter using a right side table condition, no "null" rows will be returned. I.e. you're back at a regular INNER JOIN result.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that you want the details of Users from `user` table only. Try this

```
select distinct user.*
  from api_user user
 inner join pay_app_orders order
    on user.SNO = order.user_id
 where order.origin_cost != 0 and order.status = 'S'
```